# Is it possible to send a comment to the comment section of a SharePoint site on behalf of another user?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, impersonation, comments

Is it possible to send a comment to the comment section of a SharePoint site on behave of another user. I made a SharePoint Communication site at work and I wanted my co-workers to sent comments in the comment section of my SharePoint site. Instead they mailed me.

Is it possible f.e. in PowerShell or Power automate to send a comment to the comment section of a SharePoint site on behalf of another user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my knowledge it's not possible because comment API, does not provide any parameter to provide from which user you are posting comment.

Comment API can be only called with user's context e.g. if you are calling REST API from SPFx web part then it will take current user, if you are calling REST API from Power Automate then it will take user which you used for creating Power Automate.

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge, currently there is no way to add [comments](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/01/09/all-you-need-to-know-about-commenting-in-lists/) on behalf of another users in SharePoint online.

As per [GET SharePoint list item comments using REST API](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/02/14/get-sharepoint-list-item-comments-using-rest-api/), for SharePoint online list comments, name of user who commented is stored in `author` property against the comment data and there is no way to overwrite this information as of now.

For more information check this thread: [Add Comments on list item using SharePoint REST API](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/02/14/add-comments-on-list-item-using-sharepoint-rest-api/) - check comments section.

Comment: Hi Ganesh, any new update on updating the Author and DateTime for Comments. I am using PNPCore SDK to migrate Comments from Some different platform to SP online Modern Page. Any Latest news on this much helpful.